Sonarqube scanner can't locate java home
st727s$sonar-scanner
Could not find 'java' executable in JAVA_HOME or PATH.
st727s$echo $JAVA_HOME
/Users/st727s/.sdkman/candidates/java/17-open


JAVA_HOME variable is set, also the bin path is listed under PATH variable. Sonar scanner can't seem find java executable though.
sonar scanner seems to locate brew installed jdk however, not the sdkman installed one.  Seems very vague.
Commented out the following line in zshrc (macOS)
# export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk/bin:$PATH"

